# ZF2 Doctrine 2 NoObjectExists validator with multiple fields

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a problem with Doctrine 2 NoObjectExists validator. For one field it works fine, but with multiple fields I get error:

```
Provided values count is 1, while expected number of fields to be matched is 2
```

Entity:

```
/**
 * Message
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="messages")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Message
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=32, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="assignedMessages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id")
     */
    private $user;
}
```

Fieldset class

```
    class MessageFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
    {
        protected $objectManager;

        public function __construct(ObjectManager $em)
        {
            parent::__construct('message');

            $this->setObjectManager($em);

            $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($em))
                ->setObject(new Message());



            /* User Field */
            $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'user',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'type'  => 'hidden',
                ),
            ));



            /* Name Field */
            $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'name',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'type'  => 'text',
                    'id' => 'name-label',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                ),
                'options'    => array(
                    'label' => 'Title',
                    'label_attributes' => array(
                        'for' => 'name-label'
                    ),
                )
            ));
        }

        public function getInputFilterSpecification()
        {
            return array(
                'name' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'filters'  => array(
                        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    ),
                    'validators' => array(
                        array(
                            'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                            'options' => array(
                                'messages' => array(
                                    NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'custom text'
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                        array(
                            'name' => 'Regex',
                            'options' => array(
                                'pattern' => '/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*/'
                            )
                        ),
                        array(
                            'name' => 'DoctrineModule\Validator\NoObjectExists',
                            'options' => array(
                                'object_repository' => $this->getObjectManager()->getRepository('Application\Entity\Message'),
                                'fields' => array('name', 'user'),
                                //'fields' => 'name', <--- with one field it works fine
                                'messages' => array(
                                    'objectFound' => 'Custom text'
                                ),
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
            )
        }
}
```

Form class

```
class MessageForm extends Form
{


    public function __construct(ObjectManager $em)
    {

        parent::__construct('message-form');

        $this->setAttributes(array(
            'method' => 'post',
            'role' => 'form'
        ));


        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($em));

        $fieldset = new MessageFieldset($em);
        $fieldset->setUseAsBaseFieldset(true);
        $this->add($fieldset);


        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Csrf',
            'name' => 'csrf',
            'options' => array(
                'csrf_options' => array(
                    'timeout' => 600
                )
            )
        ));



        $submit = new Element\Button('submit');
        $submit->setLabel('Add');
        $submit->setAttributes(
            array(
                'type' => 'submit',
                'class' =>'btn btn-primary'
            ));

        $this->add($submit);
    }



}
```

my action:

```
public function messageAction()
{
    $form = new MessageForm($this->em);

    $message = new Message();
    $form->bind($message);

    if ($this->request->isPost()) {
        $data = $this->request->getPost();
        //var_dump($data);   <--- it shows all values(name, user)
        $form->setData($data);


        if ($form->isValid()) {
            //...
        }else{
            //...
        }
    }

    return new ViewModel(array(
        'form' => $form
    ));
}
```

So if I set only one field(name) everything works fine, but if I pass array with fields(user, name) I get error as above.
Any idea what may be wrong in my code? In my entity user field is relation to another table so I tried set manually like this:

```
if ($this->request->isPost()) {
    $data = $this->request->getPost();
    $data->message['user'] = $this->identity() <--- obj of Entity\User
    $form->setData($data);
    ...
}
```

But it didn't work either.

Comment: Maybe this post can help you? https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/issues/252

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`DoctrineModule\Validator\UniqueObject`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/validator.md) validator like the following:

```
array(
    'name' => 'DoctrineModule\Validator\UniqueObject',
    'options' => array(
        'object_repository' => $this->getObjectManager()->getRepository('Application\Entity\Message'),
        'object_manager'  => $this->getObjectManager(),
        'fields' => array('name', 'user'),
        'messages' => array(
            'objectNotUnique' => 'Custom text'
        ),
    )
)
```

This will validate that there is no object exists with the same `name` and `user`.

Comment: It didn't help me. I still get error Provided values count is 1, while expected number of fields to be matched is 2. I don't know why, but in UniqueObject class in isValid() method there is only single value passed not array

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple fields in your `NoObjectExists` validator you also need to bind an array of values to your validator.

Read more details about this issue in the answer from Ocramius [in this post on GitHub](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/issues/252)